# How do I get a specific index of the message.author.id | Python

Tags: python, encryption, indexing, error-handling

I'm trying to encrypt a command so that you need to type your fifth added by your tenth added by your fifteenth number in your id in the end of the command to use it.

I'll probably not use it, cause I'm already using

```
if message.author.id == (my id):
```

but I want to know what's the problem.

By the way if the user tries it he will beat it in < 81 tries, so, it isn't very secret anyway.

It's saying "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

So this is my code:

```
mai = int(message.author.id)
crypto_code: int = mai[5] + mai[10] + mai[15]
```

Am I blind or not?

However I don't understand it...

Comment: Did I use "wrong" and unspecific tags? Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

'mai' is an integer and you can't use indexing/slicing for integers. What do you really need? It seems you should use a list of integers.